# Can we reduce table size in MySQL by updating fields to null

Tags: mysql, sql-update, mysql-5.7

We have a large table of size>2.5 TB.
We are planning to reduce this table size by removing unwanted fields which is about 50+ fields.
We know the removal of these fields will lead to a table rebuild and thus there will be a table lock, also we need free storage (at least same size of the table) for this operation.
So we are planning to just update these fields to null to reduce the size of the table.

Our question is

1)If we update these 50+ unwanted fields to null whether this free space will be released to OS?

2)If not, how can we make use of this free space? Will the future data insertion to this table go to this free space?

Datatype of most of the fields is varchar, TEXT, and Decimal.
We are using MySQL 5.7 in RDS.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you need to check your table structure and optimize base on your needs, for example, you can start checking the following:

1. Clean the column value will help but you will need to do `OPTIMIZE TABLE` because that space is already reserved.
2. Check if your current column type, for example, you have fields with type `TEXT`, check if can have a fixed type, for example, `VARCHAR` of 200, this is because the database will reserve that space.
3. Your table is bigger you need to check the indexes because it gonna get a lot of space and if you have unused indexes you are wasting space.
4. You can consider if you can create a historic table and create a job to move the data to the historic table if there are old data that you don't will use in the pass of time.